# How to call method in this specific method C# - Event Handler

Tags: c#, uwp

How to call method Paginate.

```
private void RegisterForPrinting()
{
               // Build a PrintDocument and register for callbacks
               printDoc = new PrintDocument();
               printDocSource = printDoc.DocumentSource;
               printDoc.Paginate += Paginate;
}

private void Paginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
{
       // As I only want to print one Rectangle, so I set the count to 1
       printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
}
```

When my code arrives the line code "printDoc.Paginate += Paginate;" i want call method Paginate, i try like i have in this example but I could not.

Comment: You don't call it manually, it's an event handler. You do something to the `PrintDocument` object that makes it raise the `Paginate` event.

Comment: @DavidG yes, i want call method Paginate like this "printDoc.Paginate += Paginate;"

Comment: @JoséMarquês - That `+=` operation isn't calling the method, it's registering it as an event handler for the `Paginate` event... You'll want to call `Paginate?.Invoke()` in the `PrintDocument`. Or, if for some weird reason you want to manually call that event handler (kinda violates SOLID), then just invoke it with `Paginate(this,null)` from wherever

Comment: @Persistence Ah, ok! But in line " printDoc.Paginate += Paginate; " this code not call method Paginate, so what happens in the code?

Comment: @JoséMarquês `printDoc.Paginate += Paginate;` means that when the `Paginate` event on the `PrintDocument` class (which `printDoc` is an instance of) is raised then the `Paginate` method (i.e. `void Paginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)`) will be called. You are attaching the method ***for a future invocation***.

Answer (score -1):

In your Class PrintDocument you have to raise the EventHandler Paginate by Calling like this:

```
Paginate?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

but if you dont want to call it by Event you can do it like this:

```
private void RegisterForPrinting()
{
    // Build a PrintDocument and register for callbacks
    printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    printDocSource = printDoc.DocumentSource;
    Paginate();
}

private void Paginate()
{
   // As I only want to print one Rectangle, so I set the count to 1
   printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
}
```